# When websocket topic is created?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I can't figure out when and where exactly the "greetings" room is created in the code.

This is my js code

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {//here it subsribe to this chat channel
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

and this is java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

}

In js I see that message will be send to "/topic/greetings", and in java code I see where will be server send answer(/topic/greetings), but where in code this topic have been created ?

Comment: Not quite, the JS code will _listen_ on `/topic/greetings` (it sends to `/hello`, according to your backend code); which is where your Java code is sending to. There's nothing to "create" really, but depending on the implementation, a topic will either start existing when clients start to listen on it or when servers publish on the topic. Note that there is an annotation `@SendTo` and Spring might very well run some setup during bootstrapping the application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I understood how it works thanks to you